# Google App Engine with DataNucleus shows Unable to instrument error message

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am using Google App Engine 1.9.2 with DataNucleus (JDO).  When I attempt to write an object to datastore I always see following error ("**SEVERE: Unable to instrument...**") the first time write operation is done.  Subsequent writes don't show this error.  Also, I see this error only when running in dev mode.  When I upload my app to production, there is no error.  But it is very frustrating to see this error during development - I spent few days to find out what exactly is happening to conclude it only shows up in dev mode.  What needs to be done to avoid this SEVERE error message from showing up?

Parent class:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Inheritance;
import javax.jdo.annotations.InheritanceStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;

@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Recipe {
    @Persistent
    private int prepTime;

    public Recipe() {
        prepTime = 99;
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Inheritance;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;

@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")
public class NewEntree extends Recipe {
    @Persistent
    private int noOfIngredients;

    public NewEntree() {
        noOfIngredients = 22;
    }
}
```

Chef class:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Inheritance;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")
public class Chef {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent(dependent = "true")
    private NewEntree favoriteRecipe;

    public Chef() {
    }

    public void setKey(Key k) {
        this.key = k;
    }

    public void setRecipe(NewEntree ne) {
        favoriteRecipe = ne;
   }
}
```

Code that does write operation:

```
PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = 
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
try {
    log.info("enter create");
    NewEntree myEntree = new NewEntree();
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Chef.class.getSimpleName(), 
            "TheChef");
    Chef myChef = new Chef();
    myChef.setKey(key);
    myChef.setRecipe(myEntree);
    pm.makePersistent(myChef);
    log.info("create done");
} finally {
    pmfInstance.close();
}
```

Errors seen in log:

```
    Apr 04, 2014 6:22:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
    SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.xxx.NewEntree. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
            at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readFrameType(ClassReader.java:1835)
            at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readFrame(ClassReader.java:1794)    ...
Apr 04, 2014 6:22:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.xxx.Recipe. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 92
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readLabel(ClassReader.java:1880)
...
Apr 04, 2014 6:22:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.xxx.Chef. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 133
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readLabel(ClassReader.java:1880)
```

Related POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So why do you have some Google "javaagent" enabled? I don't see how that is anything to do with persistence.

Comment: I think you are referring to com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.  Looks like, when Google App Engine is run in development mode it uses that package.